# Wpf trigger to change the image of a treeview item

Tags: wpf

I am binding a treeview using a Hierarchical class structure as follows.

Store
   ->ImagePath
   ->List
      ->List

When I am creating the DataTemplate for the Person, I want to use a combination of the person.name 
and the image path declared in the Store.
Here is the code behind of my MainWindow.xaml file.
`    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        Customers customers = new Customers();
        customers.Users = new List<Person> 
        { 
            new Person { Name = "John"},
            new Person { Name = "Adam"}, 
            new Person { Name = "Smith"}
        };

        Store root = new Store();
        root.ImagePath = "imageone.png";
        root.Add(customers);
        this.DataContext = root;
    }
}


public class Store : ObservableCollection<Customers> 
{
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
} 
public class Customers
{
    public string Label
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("People({0})", Users.Count());
        }
    }
    public List<Person> Users
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}`
```

and here is the xaml and this Source="{Binding Store.ImagePath}" is not working.

```
    <Window.Resources >
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}" x:Key="personKey" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Image Source="{Binding Store.ImagePath}"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="customerKey" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource personKey }" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="29" Width="112" Canvas.Left="123" Canvas.Top="5">Image one</Button>  <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="28" Width="119" Canvas.Left="249" Canvas.Top="7">Image two</Button>
        <TreeView  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding .}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource customerKey}" Height="260" Width="363" Canvas.Left="81" Canvas.Top="45" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I would also like to change the image programaticaaly and all person treeview items change when I click on of the buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataTemplate `personKey` is going to get bound to a Person object (because it's the ItemTemplate for the `customerKey` HierarchicalDataTemplate, whose ItemsSource is the Users collection).  As always in WPF, the local DataContext overrides the inherited DataContext, and the DataContext within a DataTemplate is always the object for which the DataTemplate is being materialised.

So the binding path `Store.ImagePath` is being resolved relative to the Person being displayed in the DataTemplate.  But Person doesn't have a Store property, so the binding fails.

A quick but rather kludgy way to refer to window-level properties is by using a RelativeSource binding:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=DataContext.Store.ImagePath,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```